# Help to understand the ending verb "動かねーんじゃね"

Tags: conjugations, colloquial-language, contractions, negation

Original sentence: アドビやら、お絵描き系のアプリは、誰かが実証しない限り、**動かねーんじゃね**？
I can't understand the structure of the last verb. So far I understood that 動か(conjugated form) + ねー(negative particle) + んじゃ(???) + ね(question particle).
What does んじゃ mean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

動か is the conjugated form of the verb 動く
ねー is the colloquial version of the negative auxiliary verb ない
ん is the colloquial version of the nominalization particle の
じゃ is the colloquial version of the auxiliary verb で (the dictionary form is だ)+ the particle は
ね (or ねえ, ねぇ or ねー) is also the colloquial version of ない (but the ね/ない here is an adjective not an auxiliary verb) 
So... more politely it'd be like 動かないのではないですか？or 動かないのではありませんか？And... if you put it more feminine, I'd say... 動かないんじゃない？(I think it's like "I wonder if it wouldn't work" "I doubt it would work" or "It wouldn't work, would it?" ... sorry for my poor English) ^^

Answer (score 3):

This is an colloquial way to write 動かないんじゃないか = 動かないのではないか.
〜ではないか means "is it not 〜". I.e. the whole sentence means: Is it not the case that it will not work?

That sentence is kinda weird though because it implies that something will start to work if somebody shows that it works. Perhaps he/she was sleepy when they wrote this ;p